# Selenium Webdriver return table element and implement click

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Im retrieving an element from a table but im having some trouble getting my code to implement the click on the returned element.

When the element is returned to the MC_Page_links.lnk_Brands().click() the test seems complete this step and moves onto the next line MC_Brands_Page.lnk_CreateNewBrand().click(); which produces a NoSuchElementException because the previous step MC_Page_links.lnk_Brands().click() line wasnt implemeted even though the logs says it was?

Any help would be appreciated.

Material_Brands.java

```
package appModules;


import pageObjects.MC_Brands_Page;
import pageObjects.MC_Page_links;
import pageObjects.TopNav_links;
import utility.Constant;
import utility.Utils;

public class MC_MaterialBrands_AddNewBrand_Action {
    public static void Execute(int iTestCaseRow) throws Exception{ 

    Utils.waitForElement(TopNav_links.lnk_MasterControl());

    TopNav_links.lnk_MasterControl().click();

    //Thread.sleep(1000);

    //Utils.waitForElement(MC_Page_links.lnk_Brands());

    MC_Page_links.lnk_Brands().click();

    MC_Brands_Page.lnk_CreateNewBrand().click();

    MC_Brands_Page.txtbx_CreateNewBrandName().sendKeys(Constant.MC_NewBrandName);

    MC_Brands_Page.txtbx_CreateNewBrandLogo().sendKeys(Constant.MC_Path_BrandLogo);

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    MC_Brands_Page.btn_CreateNewBrand().click();    

    }
}
```

Utils.java

```
public static WebElement getTableContents(String searchString){
     try{

            // Grab the table
            WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("LeftMenu"));
            WebElement element = null;
            // Now get all the TR elements from the table
            List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            // And iterate over them, getting the cells
            for (WebElement row : allRows) {
                List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));
             for (WebElement cell : cells) {
                // System.out.println(cell.getText());
                // System.out.println("» " +searchString);
                    if(cell.getText().equals("» " +searchString)){
                        System.out.println("inside if"+cell.getText());
                        element = cell;
                        System.out.println("Element"+cell);
                        return element;
                    }   
             }
            }
     }catch (Exception e){
                Log.error("Class Utils | Method GetTableContents | Exception occured while search table : "+e.getMessage());
                throw (e);
            }
    return null;
        }
     }
```

MC_Page_links.java

```
public static WebElement lnk_Brands() throws Exception{
    try{ 
            element = Utils.getTableContents("Brands");
            //System.out.println(element);
            Log.info("Brands link is  found on the Master Controller Page");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.error("Brands link is not found on the Master Controller Page");
        throw(e);
        }
    return element;
    }
```

index.html

```
  <table cellpadding="1" style="text-align:left; width:996px; border: none; border-spacing: 0;">
        <tr>

            <td valign="top" align="right" width="150">

                <div class="LeftMenu" style="text-align:left;">

                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="LeftMenu"><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Default.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> MC Dashboard</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Materials</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/Attribute.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Attributes</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/ProductBrand.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Brands</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItemSelected" href="/App/MC/Mat/ProductCategory.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Product Categories</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/ProductType.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Product Types</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/Product.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Products</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/ProductSet.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Product Sets</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/ProductPackagingSet.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Product Packaging Sets</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/ProductSpecials.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Product Specials</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Packing Plans</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/PackingSubContainer.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Sub Containers</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/PackingContainer.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Containers</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/PackingUnit.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Packing Units</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/PackingPlan.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Packing Plans</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/ReportPackingPlan.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Packing Plan Report</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/PackingContainerType.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Container Types</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/PackingSubContainerType.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Sub Container Types</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Bpp/PackingContainerCategory.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Container Categories</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Schedule</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/ScheduleUpload.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Upload Schedule</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/Flight.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Flights</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/FlightSet.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Flight Sets</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/Sector.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Sector Management</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/ScheduleEdit.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Schedule Edit</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/SysLog.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> System Log</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/LinePlanRules.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Line Packing Rules</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Sch/SectorTypeRules.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Sector Type Rules</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Locations</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Loc/Airport.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Airports</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Loc/AirportGroup.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Airport Sets</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Loc/Country.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Countries</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Loc/CountrySet.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Country Sets</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Loc/Warehouse.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Warehouses</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Loc/Catering.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Catering</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Inventory</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Inv/Devices.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Devices</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Inv/PhysicalContainerCode.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Containers</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Inv/BarsetNumber.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Barsets</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Inv/Translations.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Translations</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Config</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Conf/Config.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Sys Configs</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Conf/Setting.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Settings</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Conf/EDISettings.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> EDI Settings</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Conf/EDIConfig.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> EDI Config</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Conf/EmailAccount.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Email Accounts</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Fleet</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Flt/Aircraft.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Aircrafts</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Flt/AircraftType.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Aircraft Types</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Galley</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Gal/GalleyConfiguration.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Galley Configs</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Gal/BarAllocationMatrix.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Bar Alloc. Rules</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Email</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Eml/Email.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Emails</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/Sys/EmailsMissing.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Missing Emails</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Financial</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Fin/VatRate.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> VAT Rates</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Fin/VatRateCountry.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> VAT Rates per Country</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Fin/Currency.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Currencies</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Fin/CurrencyDenominationList.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Currency Denomination</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/fin/ExchangeRate.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Exchange Rates</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/PriceList.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Price List</a></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Mat/PriceTypeList.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Price Type List</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Work</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Work/Job.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Jobs</a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="MenuHead">Miscellaneous</span></td></tr><tr><td><a class="MenuItem" href="/App/MC/Misc/SealColors.aspx" title="" ><span class="LeftMenuItemPrefix">»</span> Seal Colors </a></td></tr></table><br />


            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is generally due to either the elements you are locating being inside of an `iframe`, or due to them loading slowly.  In this case, I suspect your table is contained in an `iframe`.  If you could post the HTML you are attempting to work with, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Richard, Ive added the html. The code isn't inside a iframe. When i run the getTableContents from the util class im able to get the text from each cell.

Comment: So where is ctl00_Content_miNew_sp in that html that you added?

Comment: Its way up the html page. It referees to an anchor button. Its the next step in the test. Material Brands class line MC_Brands_Page.lnk_CreateNewBrand().click(); @user1071777

Comment: Please have a look at updated description

Comment: Any way you could reformat the second table so that we can find the link that's supposed to be clicked? Right now, it's really, really hard to read because the whole thing is on one line.

Comment: Hi @bsg, Im finding the link I want but for some reason when the the element is returned to the MC_Page_links.lnk_Brands().click(); the element isnt clicked and the test moves to the next line MC_Brands_Page.lnk_CreateNewBrand().click(); which produces the error NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

Validate by setting break points on these 2 functions. 
Check whether after the function {MC_Page_links.lnk_Brands().click();} is triggered , the button is visible in the web browser , which has to be triggered by MC_Brands_Page.lnk_CreateNewBrand().click(); . if button is not visible , you will get nosuchmethodexception. In that case 
Include a delay Thread.sleep(3000 (or as per your internet/page speed)); between
 MC_Page_links.lnk_Brands().click() and MC_Brands_Page.lnk_CreateNewBrand().click() and check whether it's working.